# How can I toggle linting (code correction or even error squiggly lines) in any language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to simply temporarily (quickly) toggle the real time code correction in order to not have the squiggly distract me from the code I am trying to write.

There seems to be such a setting for specifically for python. I am looking for whether it is possible to toggle this for any language.